# Calling predict after training with polr on multicollinear data problematic

Tags: r, statistics, logistic-regression, ordinal, s

Take a look at the code below. This question has been asked before but shut down - presumably for lack of R code to reproduce the problem.

Basically, when there is multicollinearity in the data, using Polr-trained model is problematic during the call to `predict()`. What am I missing here?

**The part in bold below is what R says to me. The rest is my code.**

```
r = c(2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,1,1)
r = as.factor(r)
x = c(0,0,0,4,5,6,0,-1,-1,1)
y = c(5,5,2,1,0,3,10,4,3,8)
z = c(0,0,0,4,5,6,0,-1,-1,1)
a = data.frame(r,x,y,z)

library(MASS)
model <- polr(r~x+z, data=a, Hess=TRUE)
```

> **Warning message:
>   In polr(r ~ x + z, data = a, Hess = TRUE) :
>     design appears to be rank-deficient, so dropping some coefs**

```
test = model.frame(r~x+ z, data=a)
predict(model, test, type="class", s=model$lambda.min)
```

> **Error in X %*% object$coefficients : non-conformable arguments**

```
test2 = model.frame(r~x, data=a)
predict(model, test2, type="class", s=model$lambda.min)
```

> **Error in X %*% object$coefficients : non-conformable arguments**

```
test3 = model.frame(~x, data=a)
predict(model, test2, type="class", s=model$lambda.min)
```

> **Error in X %*% object$coefficients : non-conformable arguments**

```
model2 = polr(r~x, data=a, Hess=TRUE)
predict(model2, test, type="class", s=model$lambda.min)
```

> **[1] 1 1 1 3 3 3 1 1 1 2
>
>       Levels: 1 2 3**

```
predict(model2, test2, type="class", s=model$lambda.min)
```

> **[1] 1 1 1 3 3 3 1 1 1 2
>
>       Levels: 1 2 3**

```
predict(model2, test3, type="class", s=model$lambda.min)
```

> **[1] 1 1 1 3 3 3 1 1 1 2
>
>       Levels: 1 2 3**

Comment: For now, I've put a while loop which detects that multicollinearity was detected. It removes the ignored predictors and trains the model again.

Comment: similar problem here. you would expect the predict method to support it.

Comment: similar problem